# Why does my desktop PC wake up when I turn on my Laptop?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, desktop

I have two Windows 8 PCs. One is a desktop computer and one is a laptop. Whenever I wake up (from sleep) my laptop, my desktop computer will also wake up at the same time. I have no idea why this is occurring. I am not sure how the two systems are connected to each other (neither of them have a Microsoft account attached to them).

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 and other versions have a "wake on LAN" feature which detects various network events. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2776718 for the details and http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-use-wake-on-lan-on-windows-8-1-and-windows-8/ for step-by-step instructions.

In addition, if they are on the same desk, and you move the laptop or its mouse, that might be sufficient to shake the desktop PC's mouse, waking it.

Comment: Strange that these features are enabled by default. The article you posted shows how to enable the features so hopefully doing the opposite disables the feature.